# urllib2 won't use my proxy

Tags: python, proxy, urllib2

I'm trying to open a URL with `urllib2` using an opener I built with a HTTPS proxy, however it is requesting it with my normal IP, and not the proxy I give it.

```
import urllib2

proxy  = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'https': 'IP:PORT'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)

my_ip = opener.open('http://whatthehellismyip.com/?ipraw').read()
print my_ip
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to install opener. This should work:

```
import urllib2

proxy  = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'https': 'IP:PORT'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

my_ip = urllib2.urlopen('http://whatthehellismyip.com/?ipraw').read()
print my_ip
```

Comment: If you use this proxy from within your browser, what IP do you see when accessing this page?

Comment: I'm not using any proxy in my browser, and it displays the same when accessed in the browser: my normal IP.

Comment: @user1417933: So please set the same proxy within your browser and try again.

Comment: Tried, I'm still getting my original IP.

Comment: Okay, I removed the 's' from the https, and now it gives me the proxy IP. However, when I try visiting HTTPS pages, it sends it as my original IP. How can I resolve this?

Comment: It looks like the problem lies in the proxy. Go to the http://ip.42.pl/ URL and tell us which IP you see. Also see the headers if they contain any information about the proxy. The problem may be just you use transparent proxy for https.

Comment: I see the same result from that page: the proxy's IP when visiting via HTTP, my IP when visiting via HTTPS. Same result in the browser and script. All I know is that it's a HTTPS proxy from a public proxy list, is the issue with that and I need to find another one?

Comment: @user1417933: Yes, this proves that the issue lies on your proxy, not in the code you are trying to use.