# Urllib2 through proxy and trust untrusted SSL certificates

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, proxy, urllib2

I've read the various posts such as:

- [urllib2 won't use my proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11130184/413180)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11130306/413180
- [python ignore certificate validation urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268548/python-ignore-certificate-validation-urllib2)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1450154/413180

etc, etc, however, nothing will work for me. I want to proxy everything through my intercepting proxy (Burp Suite Pro), so I can see and edit the requests my Python 2 script makes, but I don't want it to error on the Burp CA cert being invalid. My code:

```
proxy={'http': '127.0.0.1:8081', 'https': '127.0.0.1:8081'}
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler(proxy)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
opener.context = context
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

url_request = urllib2.Request("https://example.com")
response = opener.open(url_request)
```

Also tried

```
import ssl
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.check_hostname = False
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
```

I've also tried copying the Burp `cacert.der` file to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` and running `update-ca-trust`. All give the error

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)>
```

Comment: I have the same issue